# Overclocking tools for linux - intel core duo 6600e

Tags: linux, ubuntu, overclocking

Do you know something to overclock my procesor with temperature sensor on linux?

Answer (score 3):

Over-clocking is best done when changing the setting within the BIOS.  [This](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=122731) is an older post about overclocking but the practices are still the same.

Comment: But do you know program which I could use to set frequency, check temperature and do stress tests ?

Comment: I've never done any stress testing in linux, however I did find this [forum](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=486495) that appears to be useful in that.  Setting the frequency will be easier done with the BIOS.  I don't know of any linux based software that can change frequencies.  Which leaves doing it in the terminal somehow, which makes the BIOS the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using a program called 'c2ctl' you can change the voltage and frequency parameters. using this simple program and a basic understanding of simple coding.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read How to recommend software :- [softwarerecs.se] and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User. I know the question is here and it could be a great bit of software which more than the asker will use but we now have "The Other Site.." anyway please take a couple of minutes and read:- [Help],[Answer], and [ask] just because you may want to one day, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou